# Problem with optocoupler + MOSFET circuit switch

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator

I am trying to design a simple LED switch controlled by a GPIO on an STM32. I have designed the following circuit but it doesn't work as expected:

[image]

GPIO and MCU_GND are from the microcontroller.

From my understanding, when the GPIO is high, pin 5 of the optocoupler should also be high, which would turn on the N-channel MOSFET, allowing a current to go from the external power supply 5V_ROVER to the external ground GND_ROVER.

After testing the circuit on a PCB, the MOSFET is never turned on. Pin 5 of the optocoupler is always low no matter the state of the GPIO.

I have tried to test the TLP2710 separately and it works flawlessly, but not when the MOSFET is connected so there must be a problem in the design of the circuit.

How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Well, first of all, the circuitry of the opto in your schematics does not match the actual insides of TLP2710, as it had push pull output. Then you should check if the GPIO can control the opto input, if it doesn't then opto won't output anything either.

Comment: I have measured the voltage at the input and verified on another board without the mosfet (but with the same 680 ohms input resistor) that the gpio can indeed control the input of the optocoupler, and the output is as expected. The problem is when I add the mosfet, the output stays low even when the GPIO is high (3.3 V)

Comment: Add a 10k resistor between pin 5 and Vcc to act as a collector load. GPIO high gives LED off.

Comment: @electrolux. Just curious how did you measure the ouput of the TLP2710 to confirm it worked as expected ? What was the load on the TLP2710 output in your estimation ?

Comment: I measured the voltage across pin 4 and 5 of the TLP2710 with a multimeter on a circuit that is similar to this one, but without the 4.7k resistor or the mosfet, with pin 5 left unconnected